# scrollviewer the property 'content' is set more than once

Tags: wpf, xaml, microsoft-metro

Here my code:

```
<Grid Style="{StaticResource LayoutRootStyle}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="140"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ScrollViewer 
            Grid.RowSpan="2" Style="{StaticResource HorizontalScrollViewerStyle}"
            HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" >
            <!-- The elements you want to be horizontally scrollable goes here -->
            <!-- Horizontal scrolling grid used in most view states -->

        <GridView
            Name="itemGridView"
            AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemsGridView"
            AutomationProperties.Name="Items"
            TabIndex="1"
            Padding="100,136,116,46"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource itemsViewSource}}"
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Standard250x250ItemTemplate}"
            SelectionMode="None"
            IsSwipeEnabled="false"
            IsItemClickEnabled="True"
            ItemClick="ItemView_ItemClick"/>

         <Button Hello />  <!-- From here come the Error -->           
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

When I add any thing after my `GridView`, it give me that error (the property `content` is set more than once).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer is right there in the error message. A `ScrollViewer` can only have one child (you have two, a `GridView` and a `Button`). If you want to add multiple things, you will have to wrap them in a panel that allows multiple children (e.g. `Grid`).